# Wrong gmail after sending the message from contact form. Django 2.1.5

Tags: python, django

I send message from pythonanywhere, but to my gmail coming message with my email, as sender email (from_email=to_email).

**forms.py**

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    subject = forms.CharField()
    contact_email = forms.EmailField()
    content = forms.CharField(widget=CKEditorUploadingWidget()
```

**views.py**

```
def contact(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = ContactForm()
    else:
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
            from_email = form.cleaned_data['contact_email']
            content = form.cleaned_data['content']

            try:
                send_mail(subject, content, from_email, ['****@gmail.com'], )
            except BadHeaderError:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
            return redirect('thanks')
    return render(request, 'contact.html', {'form': form})
```

**settings.py**

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '****@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '****'

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'

DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
```

*All settings for gmail.com enabled*

In the message details i found true gmail sender (in X-google-original-from)
I want put it in from_email

[image]

Comment: Because the email is still sent using *your* login details. gmail is smart enough to figure out the `from_email` is not the actual sender, but `EMAIL_HOST_USER` is. Somewhere in the full header will probably be the actual `from_email` string. But you are better off adding the `from_email` details from your form to the actual contents of the email.

Comment: How? In the form writing from_email, which adding to send_mail. Or no?

Comment: Please don't post your actual email address.

Comment: @ggdx But there is no password specified for my email.

Comment: Ok, for one, we don't need/want to know/etc. it. Two, these pages are trawled and indexed by god-knows-what spiders all the time. Do you really want your email address scraped?

Comment: @ggdx no. thnx. Could you help me with ask?

Comment: Add it to the contents: `content = "from: " + from_email + "\n\n" + content` may be good enough.

Comment: Interesting solution of this problem. But me interest, is it possible to insert the sender's gmail into form_email...

Comment: No it's not possible when using gmail. That's one reason why most sites use a specialist email provider (like sendgrid, mailgun, postmark, etc...) for transactional emails, where the from address can be specified if sent to yourself. But you can use the `reply_to` attribute of a message to specify the reply address, which is the one that shows up in your mail client.

Comment: How this make?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thnx @9769953 & @dirkgroten for help.

**views.py**

```
def contact(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = ContactForm()
    else:
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
            contact_name = form.cleaned_data['contact_name']
            from_email = form.cleaned_data['contact_email']
            content = form.cleaned_data['content']

            # try:
            msg = EmailMessage(subject, "От: " + from_email + ' (' + (contact_name) + ")\n\n" + content, from_email, ['****@gmail.com'])

            msg.send()

            # except BadHeaderError:
            #     return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
            return redirect('thanks')
    return render(request, 'contact.html', {'form': form})
```